# How to create a custom CSS class for a specific page template?

Tags: css, page-template, slug

I created a page in called "mypage".
Then I created a custom template page called "page_mypage.php".

Now, I just wanted to create some custom CSS classes in style.css.
I tried with:

```
div.page-mypage-php #myclass{}
```

but I get no results. What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The styles are not created in CSS, they are created in page markup.

If your theme and template are coded properly they make use of [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) function, that will output number of classes for you to make use of in page source.

View source of your page and `<body>` tag to see what you have available and can target in CSS for your page.

Comment: i have understood almost nothing... :(

Comment: @barbara if you need help with CSS concepts in general, [this is not the site to ask on](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). I have trouble figuring out how else to answer because I don't have clear idea what is going on in your template and CSS.